# React: shouldComponentUpdate wait for an asynchronous operation

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-native

I'm trying to show a confirm modal (using react-confirm) to warn the user when he's trying to move to another section that the information completed in the form will be lost.

The confirm of js does block the code so I can do this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (confirm('Hay cambios sin guardar, si continua se perderán. ¿Desea continuar?')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

But when I replace the confirm method by the one of the library react-confirm I can't wait for the result of this asynchronous operation.

```
async shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const response = await confirm('Hay cambios sin guardar, si continua se perderán. ¿Desea continuar?', { title: "Cambios sin guardar", okLabbel: "Sí", cancelLabel: "No!" })
        .then(
            () => {
                return true;
            },
            () => {
                return false;
            }
        );
    return (response);
```

}

Does anyone know how can I get this?

Comment: Why don't you call the confirm when user click the link/button to another section. In the success callback you can redirect user to the new section.

Comment: Because Im not using different routes to each section. A component manage the render of the information for each section, that's why Im trying to use shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: So there is a change of state involved in the transition to another section. You have nextProps, nextState parameters in shouldComponentUpdate, so you can check the state and return yes or no accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the structure of the app. I manage each section with a different route. So I implement the confirmation in the routing instead of in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another way for this issue. After clicking any button or some other actions show any modal/confirmation window.
And then add eventHandler for this window like:

```
_onClose(shouldUpdate) {
  if(shouldUpdate) {
    this.setState({}); // or this.forceUpdate()
  }
}
```